# makefile .mod compilation rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, modulefile

I'm modifying makefile of a code. After compiling, I see that some *.mod files are generated. looking online, I figured out they are module files, but I don't see a compilation rule for them. I'm trying to change the directory in which these files are generated. I can change the rule for object files, but I can't find the rule that generates *.mod files.

Looking at the makefile, can someone advise me if a line in this file generates them or how to change their directory. Here is the makefile:

```make
   # GNU Makefile

   # Paths
   SDIR=./solver
   ODIR=./obj
   _CASE=./WorkCases/problem
   CASE=$(SDIR)/$(_CASE)
   TOP = .  

   FC      =       ifort

   FFLAGS          =       -fpp -O1 -DPTR_INTEGER8 -warn nousage

   # Define rule to make .f90
   $(ODIR)/%.o : $(SDIR)/%.f90 
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $< -o $@


   # set executable name
   EXEC = $(dir ${CASE})/$(basename $(notdir ${CASE})).out


   # shared global variables
   _SHARED_OBJ =    shared_modules.o main_vars.o debug_vars.o
   SHARED_OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_SHARED_OBJ))

   OBJ     =  ${_SHARED_OBJ} $(_CASE).PARAMS.o 
   OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(SDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

   MAIN_OBJ = $(ODIR)/main.o


   main : ${SHARED_OBJ} $(OBJ) $(MAIN_OBJ) 
    $(FC) ${FFLAGS} $(OBJ) $(MAIN_OBJ) -o $(EXEC) -lstdc++ -shared-intel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the destination directory for the .mod files by using the -module compiler option.

```
-module <directory>
```

See the ifort documentation [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/694273):

> You can use the module path compiler option to specify the directory
>   in which to create the module files. If you do not use this option,
>   module files are created in the current directory.